# Implementing a Multi-Tree in SQL Server similar to one that exists in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tree, nodes

Beginner to MSSQL coding, I was asked to implement a complete tree structure, one that apparently already exists in oracle. Unsure what to do.

Implemented a simple example dataset but unsure what else a node needs for transversing and insertions.

```
Create table HeirachTree(
    NodeID int not null primary key,
    NodeName nvarchar(100) not null,
    NodeParentID int,
    NodeNext int,
    )

  NodeStructure ([Node_ID], [Node_Name], [Node_Parent_ID], [Node_Next], Node_Depth)
  AS
  (
    SELECT [NodeID], [NodeName], [NodeParentID], [NodeNext], 0
    FROM [dbo].[HeirachTree]
    WHERE [NodeParentID] IS NULL    --Select all root nodes.
    UNION ALL                       
    SELECT t.[NodeID], t.[NodeName], t.[NodeParentID], t.[NodeNext], 
      s.Node_Depth + 1              
    FROM [dbo].[HeirachTree] t
      INNER JOIN NodeStructure s
        ON t.[NodeParentID] = s.[Node_ID]
  )
SELECT                              
  Node_Name, 
  Node_Depth,
  (SELECT [NodeNext] FROM [dbo].[HeirachTree]
    WHERE [NodeNext] = NodeStructure.[Node_ID]+1) AS NextNode,
  (SELECT [NodeName] FROM [dbo].[HeirachTree] 
    WHERE [NodeID] = NodeStructure.[Node_Parent_ID]) AS ParentNode
FROM  NodeStructure
ORDER BY Node_Depth, Node_Parent_ID
```

So, found an example and had the depth calculated using a cte; for easier query on using it as a constraint.

Assumed a BFS and thought i needed a reference to the next child too. So do i map the NextID to ID using some kind of Key or joins or...? Is it even necessary?

How can i insert a specific node somewhere in the middle of my tree? 
Something like using a Select over

CASE NextID WHEN NULL then NodeDepth+=1 ELSE NodeDepth

Or is the train of thought in a completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rarely used concept existing for exactly this: [The `HIERARCHYID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017). This *data type* knows about 10 native methods like `GetDescendant` or [`GetReparentedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/getreparentedvalue-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

This example is taken unchanged from the documentation of `GetReparantedValue` and seems to demonstrate your needs.

```
DECLARE @SubjectEmployee hierarchyid , @OldParent hierarchyid, @NewParent hierarchyid  
SELECT @SubjectEmployee = OrgNode FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo  
  WHERE LoginID = 'adventure-works\gail0' ; -- Node /1/1/2/  
SELECT @OldParent = OrgNode FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo  
  WHERE LoginID = 'adventure-works\roberto0' ; -- Node /1/1/  
SELECT @NewParent = OrgNode FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo  
  WHERE LoginID = 'adventure-works\wanida0' ; -- Node /2/3/  

UPDATE HumanResources.EmployeeDemo  
SET OrgNode = @SubjectEmployee. GetReparentedValue(@OldParent, @NewParent)   
WHERE OrgNode = @SubjectEmployee ;  

SELECT OrgNode.ToString() AS Current_OrgNode_AS_Text,   
*  
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDemo  
WHERE LoginID = 'adventure-works\gail0' ; -- Now node /2/3/2/
```

Look at the various native methods...